What is the issue with my question?
A question of mine recently got closed for "needs details or clarity". I don't see what I could change to make it clearer and the person(s) who closed didn't provide any insight.
What can be changed to make it clearer?

@lulu sure but some people seem to think it shouldn't (hence a new vote to close) so I'd like to know why.

We could only speculate regarding the reason for the down and close votes.  If you want a suggestion:  add some discussion.  The case $B=F$ is well known, maybe describe that?  What if $B=2F$?  Is that qualitatively different from $B=(1+\epsilon)F$?  Simulated results are always of interest.  As I say, just speculating.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

aaand.... it's closed again for a different motive (but in a way that suggests the closer didn't read my question until the end). This is quite frustrating.

@user2661923 this protocol may work well for most people but I think some of the steps are simply not possible for me. "show all of your work, in excruciating detail" -> this would require writing a hundred-pages book and most of it would just confuse you as it would be the case for all questions I ask here.

@AnneAunyme Fair rebuttal.  However, you could summarize the results, so that knowledgeable reviewers could follow your analysis step by step.  Also, you are (perhaps) misinterpreting my comment.  I am not advocating that protocol.  Instead, I am merely indicating what defensive measure is guaranteed to work.  If you don't follow the protocol article, maybe your question gets answered anyway, and maybe it doesn't.  ...see next comment

@AnneAunyme Further, the objection that you indicate doesn't really apply to the majority of the protocol article.  If you re-read it, you will find that showing your work is only a small part of showing context.

@user2661923 Sure but similar objections can be made for a significant part of the rest. I won't deny there is still some actionable stuff there though. And now apparently someone wants to delete my question...

This question is similar to: Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 01/2022 - today). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@amWhy I did that 12 days ago. (assuming you are talking about this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531920/proving-a-random-walk-with-a-drift-is-recurrent)
